# dpkg-reconfigure tzdata not working on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Tags: timezone, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to change local timezone on Ubuntu 14.04 with the following commands.

```
$ echo Asia/Tokyo > /etc/timezone
$ dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

Current default time zone: 'Asia/Tokyo'
Local time is now:      Fri Apr 22 13:47:04 UTC 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Fri Apr 22 13:47:04 UTC 2016.
```

However, localtime is still UTC not Asia/Tokyo.

I can change the timezone with `timedatectl`.

```
$ timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Tokyo
$ timedatectl
  Local time: Fri 2016-04-22 23:07:29 JST
  Universal time: Fri 2016-04-22 14:07:29 UTC
    Timezone: Asia/Tokyo (JST, +0900)
  NTP enabled: yes
  NTP synchronized: yes
  RTC in local TZ: no
  DST active: n/a
```

Once I change timezone with `timedatectl` then I can also change with dpkg-reconfigure to any timezone.

Has anyone had the same issue?

Thanks!

Comment: This is [off topic for StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  Please ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: This is off topic. I created a [new post](http://superuser.com/questions/1068871/dpkg-reconfigure-tzdata-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty) at Super User.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo EDITOR='sed -Ei "
    s|tzdata/Areas=.+|tzdata/Areas=\"Asia\"|;
    s|tzdata/Zones/Asia=.+|tzdata/Zones/Asia=\"Shanghai\"|
    "' dpkg-reconfigure -f editor tzdata
```

Related answer: [How do you set a locale non-interactively on Debian/Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/a/1114285)